# Laravel Package Error - Class UserRepository not found

Tags: laravel, github, package

I've installed https://github.com/guilhermeslk/laravel-realtime-chat on my laravel project. This package allows to chat in real-time. Everything is okay, but when I want to create new message, I'm getting an error: **Class UserRepository does not exist**.  Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: In the sample repository you linked there is a file Repositories/User/UserRepository.php - do you have it in your app as well and does it use the correct namespace (adapted to your namespace if necessary)?

Comment: Yes, I have. I copied folder 'LaravelRealtimeChat' and added to controller 'use App\LaravelRealtimeChat\Repositories\User\UserRepository;' (I tried without part "App\" too)

Comment: I don't think that this will work. This is a complete standalone app and not meant to be included in another laravel app. It's not a package/library like e.g. Monolog.

Comment: I know, but wanted try. Thanks for your help.